# In gradient boost, do we still split nodes based on splitting criteria(impurity measure)?

Tags: classification, loss-functions, boosting, gini

Am I correct if i say that we use the loss function to calculate residuals, and the splitting criteria to determine which splits to make to predict these residuals?

If this is the case how do we handle classification tasks? Are instances that have been poorly predicted scaled by a constant to get more weight in the splitting process?

Comment: Trees in gradient boosting are not classification trees, they are regression trees. These trees are targeted to predict the gradient of the loss, and the splits are always chosen to minimize the MSE.

Comment: ... to predict the antigradient